# Homology spheres bounding homology balls but not embedding into $S^4$

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, 4-manifolds

Are there any examples of integer homology spheres $Y^3$ that bound smooth integer homology balls but that do not smoothly embeded into $S^4$?

Comment: This is a major open problem.

Comment: @Mike Miller Thanks Mike - that is what I was imagining.

Comment: @MikeMiller: do you know who might have first formulated that problem, and where?  If I were to guess I'd say perhaps Fintushel and Stern, perhaps a long ways back, but I'm not certain which paper to look in.

Comment: @RyanBudney That's a good question. I looked for a while but had no luck; I'll ask around (or maybe Danny Ruberman will see this question and know). If it helps anyone, my standard reference for existence results and discussion of this problem is your and Burton's "Census..." As a side comment, one natural place to try to look for counterexamples is $\Sigma \# \overline \Sigma$. But it is a theorem of Gompf, nicely written up in Kyle Larson's thesis, that if $\Sigma$ is $\pm 1/n$-surgery on a knot, that manifold does embed.

Comment: I talked with Danny a couple hours ago.  He seems to think the issue came up in Gilmer and Livingston's work in the 80's.

Comment: @Ryan Their paper ("On embedding 3-manifolds...) was one of the first places I checked, but no dice. They certainly did the Mayer-Vietoris argument to check that the embedding implied bounding homology balls (in their case, rational). I wouldn't be surprised if they vocalized this thought at some point. Also, Kirby Problem 3.20 is to characterize which 3-manifolds embed in 4-space; it observes that there are obstructions to bounding homology balls, but doesn't "cut the problem in half" like we want.

Comment: I talked with Livingston and he doesn't think he and Gilmer deserve credit for the question.  He suggested the weaker question is also interesting: whether or not a punctured homology sphere smoothly embeds in S^4.

Comment: @Ryan Right, by passing to the boundary of a tubular neighborhood that is equivalent to the question of whether $\Sigma \# \overline{\Sigma}$ embeds.

Comment: @RyanBudney Thanks for the follow up.  I am confused, are you talking about a 4-dimensional or a 3-dimensional punctured homology sphere embedding in $S^4$?  Aren't there lots of examples of 3-dimensional homology spheres embedding in $S^4$ - so any of those you could just puncture.  And in the 4-dimensional case - wouldn't this be false assuming Schoenflies?

Comment: 3-dimensional punctured homology spheres embedding in $S^4$.  There are examples, of course, but we don't know which ones embed and which ones do not.  Similarly there are examples of un-punctured homology spheres embedding, but we don't know which ones embed, and which ones do not.

Comment: The Poincaré homology $3$-sphere does not smoothly embed
in the $4$-sphere but does have a topologically
bi-collared embedding.  Hence, it bounds topological (but
not smooth) homology $4$-balls to either side.

Comment: @DavidSnyder I believe every 3-dimensional homology sphere bounds a topological contractible 4-manifold (But this is a hard theorem of Freedman).  By doubling this we get a 4-sphere (again - a theorem of freedman)

Comment: @user1010 Not quite. [Kervaire](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-144-00/S0002-9947-1969-0253347-3) (1969)  gives an example of an integral homology $3$-sphere that does not bound a contractible $4$-manifold. (see page 69)

Comment: @DavidSnyder He is talking about bounding a smooth manifold. The Freedman result as cited is true.

Comment: @MikeMiller Ah, right! thanks, that's not my usual world.

Comment: So, Kervaire's example isn't smoothable (though topologically flat) which was basically observed by Freedman in his paper.

Comment: @DavidSnyder I didn’t check the paper but my guess is that kervaire showed that the poincare homology sphere can’t bound any smooth homology ball (by Rochlin’s theorem) but certainly didn’t construct any topological one. All that stuff is freedman - and it appears to be pretty far from “observed” caliber.

Comment: @user101010 Right, Kervaire's example is simply connected, definitely not contractible (has non-trivial $H_2$), I had to go back to the paper (and in hindsight that it was not contractible should have been obvious). Still, the Note that Freedman makes immediately after stating his own Theorem 2 (homology 3-spheres embed top. flatly in S^4) does state explicitly that the topological ball bounded by the Poincaré sphere can't be smoothed, as shown by the Rochlin invariant --this was the observation I was writing about, not the much harder result (Theorem 2), indeed far from being an observation.

Answer (score 4):

The first examples (infinitely many of them) are given in [Clayton McDonald's recent note](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.02696). In particular, the double branched cover of the knot depicted in Figure 1 bounds a homology ball but does not embed into any homotopy 4-sphere.

Of course, the existence of a homology sphere which embeds into a homotopy sphere but not $S^4$ is still open, because it's still open whether homotopy spheres are $S^4$.

Comment: What about the double of the closure in $\ S^3\ $ of $\ S^3\setminus A^3\ $? where $\ A^3\subset S^3\ $ is the topological (closed) ball such that its complement has a (highly) nontrivial fundamental group?

Comment: That doesn't sound to me like a smooth manifold. OP is asking about compact smooth 3-manifolds without boundary and with the same homology as a sphere, and their smooth embedding properties into $S^4$, whereas your examples are not even obviously topological manifolds (when they are known to be it is often the case the result is $S^3$, such as for the Alexander cell A).

Comment: MME, thank you. Somehow "smooth" next to homology, in the same phrase, didn't register on my mind -- homology goes smoothly with something like "singular (homology)". My fault.

Comment: @WlodAA No worries, that makes sense. Your question is interesting in its own right. McDonald answers the smooth question and Freedman answers the question for topological manifolds, and you pose the question for homology-manifolds (spaces with same local homology as Rn). Perhaps some sewing of crumpled cubes bounds a homology-manifold but does not embed in S4?

Comment: Are there mflds $\ M^n\ $ that do not admit a smooth structure but $\ M^n\times\mathbb R^k\ $ does?

Comment: I am a 3 or 4-dimensional topologist so let me give an example in that spirit. It is a remarkable fact that many topological 5- and 6-manifolds admit smooth structures. Combining Theorem 1 (which implicitly assumes CLOSED manifolds, but works for the manifold with boundary $M^4 \times D^2$, as remarked below the theorem) and Theorem 2, we see that if $M$ is any 4-manifold with $H^3(M;\Bbb Z/2) = 0$ with zero Kirby-Siebenmann invariant then $M \times \Bbb R^2$ is smoothable. (Note they identify the degree-4 obstruction as KS(M) at the beginning of p2.)

Comment: So one may take any closed topological 4-manifold M with KS(M) = 0. A celebrated example is Freedman's "E8 manifold", a closed topological manifold with negative-definite intersection form E8. This form is not diagonalizable over Z so Donaldson's diagonalizability theorem asserts M is not smoothable. Further, KS(M) = 0 whenever the intersection form of M is even. So I propose to take M to be Freedman's E8-manifold and use those results to see $M \times \Bbb R^2$ is smoothable, in fact even $M \times D^2$.

Comment: MME, impressive!

Comment: @mme your construction in the comments works, except the part that the E8 manifold has KS=0 (but E8 connected sum with itself will have the property you want). It's not true that the KS is zero whenever the form is even. It is true however that for closed, topological, spin 4-manifolds, KS equals the signature/8 mod 2 -- for more information you could look at Freedman-Quinn's book, Section 10.2B.

Comment: @AruRay Thanks for correcting that comment!